# How to create a DIY magnetic horn?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electric-current, neutrinos

I recently watched a video about Neutrino Beam from Symmetry Magazine and I did some research about how to create a magnetic horn. I came-up with a paper from CERN that explained how to create one. But, it seemed advanced but looking into the working principle of magnetic horn it seemed it should be simple. Can someone explain or tell how to create a DIY magnetic horn?

**Here's the CERN paper link:** https://cds.cern.ch/record/131737/files/SCAN-9804063.pdf

Comment: Not possible  to do it yourself. see the wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_horn . also called neutrino horns https://www.energy.gov/articles/what-neutrino-horn

Comment: If I've a high magnetic flux capacity magnet and place it adjacent to an Alumunium horn, Can I accomplish it?

Comment: do you have a beam of charged particles to focus?

Comment: I do have one! Technically it's a proton beam but I want to focus it (converting it into 
 a neutrino beam) onto a target

Comment: protons do not decay, the horns are used to focus particles that decay into neutrinos.

Comment: Yeah! I know that. That's why, I'll shoot the proton beam onto a target then get pion to focus only positive pions and that'll eventually decay into neutrinos. And I want to know, If a Aluminium Horn with adjacent powerful magent can create a magnetic horn or not?

Comment: You should contact one of the writers of the papers to get a correct answer. The magnet is with electromagnetic currents , and the wires are around the aluminum foil, ( see description of *how they work* in last link I gave) with very high currents, but I cannot answer your  question. In addition neutrinos are weakly interacting particles and to see their interaction needs large detectors etc.etc.